# How can I shuffle custom list-like data in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, shuffle, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I am attempting to rearrange the order of a deck (or `Hand` of cards). Essentially to shuffle the hand. Namely, I want to shuffle the `fullDeck` into a random order. However, as I'm still kind of new to Haskell, I would appreciate any sort of assistance, here's the code, and classes etc:

```
data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Card = Card Rank Suit
      deriving (Eq, Show)

data Rank = Numeric Integer | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
            deriving (Eq, Show)

data Suit = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs
            deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Here is how the deck is being made, constructed.

fullDeck :: Hand
fullDeck = createHandFromList (suitedCardList Clubs ++
                suitedCardList Diamonds ++
                suitedCardList Hearts ++
                suitedCardList Spades) Empty

suitedCardList :: Suit -> [Card]
suitedCardList s = [Card r s | r <- [Numeric 2, Numeric 3, Numeric 4,
                                     Numeric 5, Numeric 6, Numeric 7,
                                     Numeric 8, Numeric 9, Numeric 10,
                                     Jack, Queen, King, Ace]]

createHandFromList :: [Card] -> Hand -> Hand
createHandFromList [] h     = h
createHandFromList (c:cs) h = Add c (createHandFromList cs h)

draw :: Hand -> Hand -> (Hand, Hand)
draw Empty h       = error "draw: The deck is empty."
draw (Add c h1) h2 = (h1, Add c h2)

shuffleDeck :: StdGen -> Hand -> Hand
shuffleDeck g Empty = Empty
shuffleDeck g h     = undefined
```

So I'm very curious as to how I should code `shuffleDeck` so that it shuffles it, I think an important note that Deck or Hand can be used interchangeably as a Deck is a collection of cards, just like a hand.

So far I've tried implementing a number of helper functions, but I'm not sure if this is heading in the right or wrong direction...

```
takeNthCard :: Hand -> Integer -> (Card, Hand)
takeNthCard h 0 = (nthCard, Add nthCard h) --Move nth card to hand
takeNthCard h n = n - 1 --(and move along list of cards)
```

Many thanks in advance for any advice given!

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard done, hope it's more useful :D

Comment: I would remove `Numeric Integer` from `Rank` and make a sum type starting with Ace | Two | Three .. King. Then derive Enum. Then all you need to do is shuffle a list made of the enumerated values, starting with the lowerbound and ending with the upper bound. That shuffled list of values will tell you how to order a deck.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I can't change the classes, I've written MANY other functions (not included because they weren't relevant for the question) for them, which are all based on this class setup.

Comment: You don't have any classes. You have some types, and some functions.

Comment: You could make a list [1 .. 52], shuffle it, and then map each number to a card.

Comment: Not clear whether this is really what you would like to do, but the problem of randomly shuffling a list (of length 52) has been discussed for example in [SO question 33723097](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723097/random-numbers-in-haskell-and-shuffling-a-list).

Comment: what you call classes are known as algebraic data types in Haskell. They are comparable to C's unions of structs, with each union [tagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) by a unique identifier.